# Improve perfomance of Odata Controller Get()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, odata

A LINQ query returns 17000 records. A Odata controller Get() return this query but it takes more than 6 min How I reduce the time.

Comment: You would NOT get all of the records at once. Even if you get them, your browser will just freeze! Instead, use some pagination to get specific amount at a time. Imagine you have  multi requests to get that amount of data!

Comment: you need to use filters and paginations: https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#entitySet

Answer (score 0):

you can try and add paging logic to your query, the concept is to fetch only a set amount of records each time instead of all of them which may reduce your query time.

note that this solution work only if your client will also be able to support the paging logic.

refer to these articles to see possible implementations:

ODATA:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging

SQL:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/paging-through-a-query-result

Comment: As this answer may help the OP, it's always good to write the code here and not paste a link because the content maybe deleted.

Comment: The query time less than 15 sec but when it returns it takes more than 6 min.

Comment: the client does not support the paging logic.

Comment: adding paging logic to you odata API will reduce the 6 minutes time, but if the client cannot support it we are facing an issue.

Comment: did you try to identify the bottleneck? i suppose it is not the network that causes the entire 6 minute delay, perhaps it has something to do with the serialization of the data?

Comment: Any other solutions.

Comment: my best bet is the serialization of the objects takes time, try and keep them already serialized as JSON on the server side and returning that. 
if you see a considerable time decrease that may be a valid point of slowness

Comment: If I serialized the SQL query result in JSON on the server side then how I return that.  I am trying to return as a string it gives me an error "the 'object content 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content-type 'application/XML"

Comment: try and change content-type header to application/Json